# django frontend inline form for ManyToMany displayed as table with add option

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many, django-widget

I need a way to add (and edit) elements (connected with M2M) in a frontend (not admin) form.

My Models:

```
class IngredientName(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_('name of ingredient'), max_length=255)

class Unit(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_('unit name'), unique=True, max_length=255)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey(IngredientName)
        unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
        value = models.FloatField()

class Recipe(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=250)
        portions = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('portions'))
        ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
        description = models.TextField(_('description'))

Forms:

    class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Recipe
```

views:

```
class addRecipe(CreateView):
    form_class = RecipeForm
```

In a first step I've tried to use  `IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Ingredient,Recipe, form=RecipeForm)` but i just got an error:

```
<class 'recipe.models.Recipe'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'recipe.models.Ingredient'>
```

Whats the best, and reusable way, to do this? does a widget exist for this?

Comment: what do you mean by add and edit? do you want to create a form for your models?

Comment: yes i need an inline subform to add ingredient elements